# When $d \mid n$, the number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ is $\phi (d)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

If $d$ is a positive divisor of $n$, the number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic subgroup of order $n$ is $\varphi (d)$

where $\varphi(d)$ is the Euler's totient function, denoting the number of positive numbers less than $d$ that are coprime to $d$.

The question I have concerns a part of the proof:

If $d \mid n$ then there exists exactly one subgroup of order $d$ , call it $\langle a \rangle$.  **Then every element of order $d$ also generates the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$** and an element $a^k$ generates $\langle a \rangle$ iff $\gcd(k,d) = 1$ **implies that the number of such elements is precisely $\varphi (d)$.**

How does every element of order $d$ also generate the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$, wouldn't it be only one $a$ since $|\langle a \rangle| = |a|$?  And how does this fact imply $\varphi(d)$ is the correct number?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_5$.  Under addition we have $$\mathbb{Z}_5=\langle 1 \rangle=\langle 2 \rangle=\langle 3 \rangle=\langle 4 \rangle$$

A cyclic group has **at least** one generator, but if it is finite, then it will have exactly $\phi (n)$ total, where $G$ is your cyclic group and $n=\left| G \right|$.  So equivalently, you could define the finite cyclic group of order $n$ as the group with exactly $\phi(n)$ generators, but it would need to be proven that this is equivalent to being generated by a single element.

Comment: But why does every element of order $d$ generate the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$?  I know that $|\langle a \rangle | = |a| = d$, but doesn't this imply that only one element generates $\langle a \rangle$?

Comment: No, $|\langle a \rangle |=|a|=d$ just implies that it is generated by **at least** one element; namely $a$.  If $|b|=d$ for $b \in \langle a \rangle$, where $|\langle a \rangle |=d$, then $b$ must generate all the elements of $\langle a \rangle$, because $\langle a \rangle$ only **has** $d$ elements.  If $\langle b \rangle$ generates exactly $d$ elements, then it must generate all the elements.  Remember $b^r \in \langle a \rangle$

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\langle a\rangle $ is a finite cyclic group of order $n$ and $d\mid n$.

Then $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$ say $H_d$  and $H_d=\langle a^{\frac{n}{d}}\rangle$ ( see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4329046/977780) for proof).

Now number of elements of order $d$ are precisely the number of generators of $H_d$.

$a^{r}\in H_d$ generates  $H_d$ iff $1\le r\le d$ and $\gcd(r, d) =1$

$($ $|a^r|=\frac{d}{\gcd(r, d) }$ . Then $|a^r|=d$ iff $\gcd(r, d) =1$$)$

Hence the number of generators of $H_d$ is exactly $\varphi(d) $ which are precisely the elements of order $d$.

---

[Given $G=\langle a\rangle$, $|G|=n$ and $d\mid n$, show $G$ has a unique subgroup of order $d$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4329046/977780)

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=\langle a\rangle $ is a finite cyclic group of order $n$ and $n=dk$.

$a^n=e\Rightarrow a^{kd}=e$, define $a^k=b\Rightarrow b^d=e$, so we can find a unique subgroup with order $d$.

Define: $H=\langle b\rangle$, now this problem is converted to: how many generators to generate $H$?

One natural choice is $\langle b\rangle$, then how to find other generators of $H$, such that $\langle b^s\rangle=\langle b\rangle$?

So how many choices for $s$? ($1\leq s\leq |\langle b \rangle|$)

Note that $|\langle b\rangle|=d$, and we have $\langle b^s\rangle=\langle b^{\gcd(s, d)}\rangle$, hence

$d=|\langle b\rangle|=|\langle b^s\rangle|=|\langle b^{\gcd(s, d)}\rangle|=\frac{d}{\gcd(s, d)}\Rightarrow \gcd(s, d)=1$

So we need to count the number of $s$ such as $\gcd(s, d)=1$, which is exactly equal to $\phi(d)$.

Answer (score 0):

An element of order d generated a subgroup of order d which is $<a>$ since $<a>$ is unique.

A subgroup of order $d$ is isomorphic to $Z/d$ if $[n]$ generates $Z/d$, $[1]=m[n]$ this is equivalent to saying $1=mn+cd$, thus $gcd(d,n)=1$. Thus there exists $\phi(d)$ generators.

Comment: So $a$ generated the subgroup $\langle a \rangle$, therefore there is only one element whose order is $d$?

Comment: I suppose you have understood that there is only one subgroup of order d

Comment: A subgroup of $Z/n$ of order $d$ is generated by $[n/d]$.

Comment: But the proposition is saying that the number of elements of order $d$ is $\phi (d)$, which isn't always $1$, so how can there be only one element that has order $d$ that generates $\langle a \rangle$?