# Why mismatch in finding number of elements of given order in cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is stated [here](https://sharmaeklavya2.github.io/theoremdep/nodes/abstract-algebra/groups/cyclic-groups/order-of-elements-in-cyclic-group.html) :

In a cyclic group of order $n$, the order of $a^k = \frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}.$
Further, the distinct elements that have order $n/d$ are :
$a^{di}: i\in\mathbb{Z_{n/d}^{\times}}$

So, for $n=8$, check for different values of order $n/d= 8, 4, 2,1$:

$|a^1|= 8/1= 8,$
$|a^2|= 8/2= 4,$
$|a^4|= 8/4= 2,$
$|a^8|= 8/8= 1,$

The distinct elements that have order $8/1= 8$ are :
$a^{i}: i\in\mathbb{Z_{8}^{\times}}$

The distinct elements that have order $8/2= 4$ are :
$a^{2i}: i\in\mathbb{Z_{4}^{\times}}$

The distinct elements that have order $8/4= 2$ are :
$a^{4i}: i\in\mathbb{Z_{2}^{\times}}$

The distinct elements that have order $8/8= 1$ are :
$a^{i}: i\in\mathbb{Z_{1}^{\times}}$

---

The above shows one element of order $8$, but there are two: $a,a^7$.

The set generated under multiplication operation by $\langle a \rangle =\{a,a^2,a^3,a^4,a^5,a^6, a^7,e\},$
The set generated under multiplication operation by $\langle a^7 \rangle = \{a^7,a^6,a^5,a^4,a^3,a^2, a^1, e\}.$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4497453/977780

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $a, a^3, a^5, a^7$ are generators of $G=\{e,a,a^2,...,a^7\}$, because they are coprimes of 8.

Comment: But, still the formula is correct?

Comment: Correct. @jiten

Comment: Unable to understand why it is correct, or how to make it correct for $C_8$ two co-prime values as generators.

Comment: you can list them, to get some intuition. @jiten

Comment: Even $a^3=\{a^3, a^6, a, a^4, a^7, a^2, a^5, e\}, a^5$ are generators.

Comment: right, because you only listed $a$ and $a^7$ in you last two lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula says the elements of order $8$ are $a^i$ for $i\in\mathbb Z_8^\times$. Since $\mathbb Z_8^\times=\{1,3,5,7\}$, this means the elements of order $8$ are $a, a^3, a^5$ and $a^7$, which is correct.

Comment: Sorry, but couldn't understand the meaning of  $\mathbb Z_8^\times$. If please could tell in a line or two, would be highly thankful.

Comment: @jiten It's the group of units of the ring $\mathbb $Z_8$. Its members are those elements of $\mathbb $Z_8 that have multiplicative inverses in this ring.